# How to remove all the items inside the stack in python

Tags: python-2.7, stack

stack=['Hatdog','Hamburger']

stack.empty()

print (stack)

Comment: Hi. As written, it's difficult to understand what your end goal is. Are you trying to empty the variable for use later? Is this a homework exercise?

Comment: it's a part of my activity and i'm trying to remove all the items inside the stack. Thank you for you answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you implemented the stack using list, you should iterate over the list, until it's empty, for example like this:

```
stack=['Hatdog','Hamburger']

while (not stack == []):
    stack.pop()

print (stack)
```

Check this link on stack implementations in Python: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-in-python/